# how to add html to another html. Tried everything but still does not work

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add subscribe.html to index.html.
I researched everywhere and used all the forms but it does not work. Does not show any content in my subscribe.html.
I will be glad if you guys can let me know how to handle this problem.
This is the code in index.html.

```
 <footer>
      <script>
        subscribe.html;
      </script>
      <h3>Subscribe &nbsp; &nbsp; NewsLetter &nbsp; &nbsp; Help &nbsp; &nbsp; Instagram &nbsp;</h3>
    </footer>
    <object data="html/subscribe.html"> </object>
  </body>
</html>
```

this is code in subscribe.html

```
<p>hey</p>
<!-- modify this form HTML and place wherever you want your form -->

<form action="https://formspree.io/mjvazzkn" method="POST">
  <label>
    Your email:
    <input type="text" name="_replyto" />
  </label>
  <label>
    Your message:
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
  </label>

  <!-- your other form fields go here -->

  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

this is the photo of my website.
[image]

Comment: In the `data="html/subscribe.html">` part is "subscribe" in a directory "html" relative to the index Peter

Comment: @gaefan that seems like a lot of extra libraries for something that can be done with native html or very least fetch

Answer (score 1):

In the `data="html/subscribe.html">` part is "subscribe" in a directory "html" relative to the index page? Try just `data="./subscribe.html"`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use javascript `fetch` technology to solve the problem. It is a new and very elegant technology

Read on at - >

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch